# Ensure Scrapy stay logged in during extended crawl

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I have my Spider that needs to stay logged in to website for extended crawl:

```
 start_urls = ['https://example.com/login']
 crawl_urls = ["www.example.com/page1",
               "www.example.com/page2",
               "www.example.com/page1000"]


 def parse(self, response):
        token = response.xpath('//*[@name="csrf_token"]/@value').extract_first()
        return [scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                                 formdata={'csrf_token': token,
                                                           'password': 'mypassword',
                                                           'username': 'myusername'},
                                                 formcss='.login_form_widget .form',
                                                 callback=self.check_login_response)]

    def check_login_response(self, response):
        if b"Incorrect username or password" in response.body:
            self.log("Login failed", level=logging.ERROR)
            return
        else:
            self.log("Successfully logged in!!")
            for url in self.crawl_urls:
                yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.scrape)

    def scrape(self, response):
        # scraping
        yield item
```

The issue is that some of the data on the page are only visible when logged in. So my spider can scrape those data when it's logged in. But some records are missing those data, which I have discovered that Scrapy crawled those pages when not logged in.

I am thinking of checking the response page if its HTML contains my `username`, then it's logged in.

Where, in my code, should I make Scrapy check itself if it's logged in and perform logging in if not?